# Find the Latest file version in a folder using Python

Tags: python, windows, file, directory

Ive been trying to get python to try to search all my shots

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob
latest = sorted(glob.glob('dd19_15_00_an[0-9]+\.avi'))[-1]
```

**Note**: a normal sort is OK if your versions have zero padding. If they had no zero padding, you needed some kind of natural sort, which complicated things a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't `latest = sorted(glob.glob('dd19_15_00_an[0-9]+\.avi'))[-1]` be enough?

Comment: where do i insert the "C:\Documents and Settings\nick.grobler\My Documents\My stuff\" part?

Comment: it also gives me this error " IndexError: list index out of range
"

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a tree representation of your files, recursively
2. Do the search

For "02" suffixes it's quite easy, you use a regex like `[0-9]+`. However what happens for other kind of suffixes or prefixes? You could implement something that calculates the [levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance) only in some given intervals.